# Couldn't see RegionServer in Terminal-LINUX-HBASE

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I installed hadoop and my HBase is running on top of it. All my deamons in hadoop is up and running. After i started my hbase i could see the HMaster running when i gave the JPS command.

I'm running my hadoop in Pseudo distributed mode . When i checked my localhost it shows regionserver is running.

But why couldn't i see the HRegionServer running in my Terminal in Linux?

Comment: What do the logs say? How are you confirming if the Region server is running. is it merely through jps? For the url http://<hostname>:60010/master-status , do you see the region server listed under <p>Region Servers</p>

Comment: Yes i could see my region server in localhost:60010. But in my Linux-Terminal when i gave JPS command it doesn't show Hregionserver. Why is that? @MaghamRavi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be because `hbase.cluster.distributed` is not set or set to false in `hbase-site.xml` .
According to http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html :

> hbase.cluster.distributed : 
>   The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are false for
>   standalone mode and true for distributed mode. If false, startup will
>   run all HBase and ZooKeeper daemons together in the one JVM. Default:
>   false

So if you set it to **true** you'll see the distinct master, region server and ZooKeeper processes. E.g: a pseudo-distributed Hadoop/HBase process list would look like this:

```
jps
3991 HMaster
4209 HRegionServer
3140 DataNode
3464 TaskTracker
3246 JobTracker
2942 NameNode
3924 HQuorumPeer
```

Comment: +1 for solving my problem as I was so confused why the HQuorumPeer and HRegionServer processes werent getting displayed